How to resolve the issue of Spring Boot not being able to find a class?
I clearly have a class SubjectCategoryDTOConvert in the directory com.jingdianjichi.subject.application.controller.convert, which I wrote as an interceptor, but it is still throwing an error.
enter image description here
Enter image description here My project structure is as follows: Enter image description here
When I sent this POST request, it was like this: Enter image description here The POST request returned a 500 status code and did not insert data into my database.
enter image description here
I checked my Maven configuration, and I have included the dependency for this class, but it still shows that it cannot be found. What could be the issue and how can I resolve it?
enter image description here

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Edit the question and include code fragments.
